# Javascript to sum the values in grid and show in footer of grid

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, javascript

Hi all currently i am working on a javascript function which needs to display the sum of the gridview cells in the footer row. Now i am able to get the answer but i am unable to save the value in the footer row.
        Can anyone pls help me in saving the value to the gridview footer label. Thanks in advance.

Here is my js function.

```
    function addTotal() {
        var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var Total = '0.0';
        var Sample;
        var val;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i].type == "text") {
                if (input[i].id.indexOf("txtpercent") > 0) {
                    Sample = document.getElementById(input[i].id).value;
                    var val = parseFloat(Sample.replace(",", ""));

                    if (isNaN(val) == true) {
                        val = 0;
                    }

                    Total = parseFloat(Total) + val;
                    //document.getElementById("Flblallocationpercent").innerHTML=Total;
                }
            }
        }
        alert(Total);
        if (Total != 100) {
            alert("Allocation should be equal to 100 %")
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the design part from where the function is called

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allocation Percentage">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpercent" runat="server" Text="" OnTextChanged="allocate_sum"
                                            Visible="true" ToolTip="Percentage" onblur="addTotal()" />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate >

                                        <asp:Label ID="Flblallocationpercent" runat="server" Enabled="true" Width="95%" />

                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: did you ensure that the DOM has the element to Id `Flblallocationpercent`

Comment: Flblallocationpercent is the name of the footer label. I am not sure it has element to ID. Tats why i have commented that line

Comment: by default the id and the name will be the same for the server side controls. Just check if that control is in DOM and also check after un commenting out that line if you have any javascript errors in that page.

Comment: i receive the following error.. 
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: so it means that the element is not in the `DOM`. Please check the page source and ensure that the element is in the DOM. Once it is available, your code will work nice.

Answer (score 0):

Refer Following Javascript Function:

```
for (var i = 1; i < gridLength - 1; i++) {


                    sprice = grid.rows[i].cells[3].innerText;

                    sprice = sprice.replace(code, "");

                    sprice = sprice.replace(",", "");
                    if (sprice == "")
                        price = 0;
                    else
                        price = parseFloat(sprice);


                    subTotal = subTotal + parseFloat(price);

                }
```

Go through [THIS](http://forums.asp.net/t/1893584.aspx/1) link , you will also get code behind referances.

Hope its helpful.

Comment: in which place the value is binded in footer of the grid

Comment: I have provided you a link, on that link its clearly shown binding value to footer

Answer (score 0):

Please note the below mentioned code, Assign cssclass to both the Textbox and Label.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allocation Percentage">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpercent" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true" ToolTip="Percentage" CssClass="txtAmount" onblur="addTotal()" />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate >

                                        <asp:Label ID="Flblallocationpercent" runat="server" CssClass="TotalValue" ForeColor="Red" Width="95%" />

                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Add the following Javascript function on your head section,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">                     

            function addTotal() {

                var Total = '0.0';
                var Sample;

                $(".txtAmount").each(function(){


            Total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            });

            alert(Total);
            $(".txtAmount").val(Total);
                    //OR
            $(".txtAmount").html(Total);
        }
</script>
```

And check whether it solves your problem. Hope it helps

Comment: No.. It doesn't work. The value is displayed as some undefined value(0.NanNanNan......) though it does not show in footer..